# Question regarding Compatibility of Ant 1.6.5 Apache Vs Ant 1.8.2

Tags: ant

i have coded one script using Ant apache 1.8.2 version but i want to run this in Ant apache 1.6.5 vesion.Will this craete problem regarding version compatibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The release notes for Ant 1.8 give a [list of changes that could break older versions](http://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/RELEASE-NOTES-1.8.0.html). See if you're using any of those which could break.